# Object tag overlays div tag, How can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's jsfiddle.

I put it up on this with an activeX object.

please allow your browser to install it to reproduce this error.

http://jsfiddle.net/hA5fy/

And quick code preview here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wanttooverlay" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:Red; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"></div>
    <OBJECT style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue;" id="Rdviewer" classid="clsid:ADB6D20D-80A1-4aa4-88AE-B2DC820DA076" type="application/html" codebase="rdviewer50.cab#version=5,0,0,239" >
        <param wmode="transparent" />
    </OBJECT>
</body>
</html>
```

I've done things to solve like setting z-index, putting param wmode="transparent", and that sort of things.

But nothing seems to be a solution for me.

The red box will be a datepicker in my application.

Can this be done with just manipulating CSS?

And FYI, I'm implementing the object tag through script on document ready.

would it be a problem for this??

hope somebody could fix this.

Comment: Seems your question is not about JavaScript, so please remove it from the question tags

Comment: @ABFORCE I'm looking for a javascript-way solution too.

Answer (score 2):

In `OBJECT` inline styling:

Insert:

```
position:absolute;
```

Change to:

```
<OBJECT style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue;position:absolute;" id="Rdviewer" classid="clsid:ADB6D20D-80A1-4aa4-88AE-B2DC820DA076" type="application/html" codebase="rdviewer50.cab#version=5,0,0,239" >
    <param wmode="transparent" />
</OBJECT>
```

**Note:**

- Try to avoid inline styling.
- `z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
  position:relative, or position:fixed).

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hA5fy/1/)**

Comment: Does this work for you? not for me. I tested it on IE11. I know how z-index works. In your demo, the object tag still displays over the red box. am I missing something on your instruction?

Comment: Where do you want it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Where. But I'm trying to make the div with id "wanttooverlay" covers the object tag on screen.

Comment: In your original code the OBJECT tag wasn't even visible. And you have set different width and height to both the div and the object

Comment: Do you just want wanttooverlay over the object tag? because of different width's it won't fully cover it

Comment: Sorry for using 'cover' word. I want the red div to be displayed over the object tag. If the object tag was invisible, activeX must be the cause.

Comment: the #wanttooverlay div will be actually a datepicker in my app, I mentioned this above. It must be displayed over the OBJECT tag because It's datepicker. I just made a sample HTML for this.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. OBJECT tag still got the first. I already mentioned that I've worked through with z-index stuff. I'm going to cry...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57801/discussion-between-imbondbaby-and-hina10531).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be removing `position:absolute` from your `div` or If you want these elements to be float on the page put them into a `div` wrapper with absolute position

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0">
    <div id="wanttooverlay" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:Red"></div>
    <OBJECT style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue;" id="Rdviewer" classid="clsid:ADB6D20D-80A1-4aa4-88AE-B2DC820DA076" type="application/html" codebase="rdviewer50.cab#version=5,0,0,239" >
        <param wmode="transparent" />
    </OBJECT>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to lay out your `div` on top of the `OBJECT` element, the solution is pretty simple, just swap these elements in your HTML codes

```
<body>
    <OBJECT style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue;" id="Rdviewer" classid="clsid:ADB6D20D-80A1-4aa4-88AE-B2DC820DA076" type="application/html" codebase="rdviewer50.cab#version=5,0,0,239" >
        <param wmode="transparent" />
    </OBJECT>
    <div id="wanttooverlay" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:Red; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"></div>
</body>
```

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9haE/1/)

Comment: I don't want the elements to float. I just want the #wanttooverlay div to be displayed over the OBJECT tag.

Comment: @hina10531 If you want the `div` to be displayed over the OBJECT tag, the solution is pretty simple, see my updated post

Comment: Are you seeing a blue background on OBJECT? that means ActiveX isn't active there. Once you activates it, you will see that OBJECT still stays on the top of the red bg div.

Comment: And dragging down the OBJECT has nothing to do with making OBJECT windowless.